# php mysql query error with "where"

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I'm running a query on our customer order database to see the sales from the last week. The query looks like this:

```
select
distinct day(from_unixtime(customerorder.datetime)) as day,
count(distinct customerorder.customerorderid) as count_totalorders,
count(distinct customerorderpos.itemid) as count_differentitems,
sum(customerorderpos.quantity_ordered) as quantity_ordered,
sum(customerorderpos.itemsubtotal) as item_subtotal,
sum(customerorderpos.pricechangetotal) as item_pricechangetotal,
sum(customerorderpos.itemtotal) as item_total,
sum(customerorderpos.purchase_price * customerorderpos.quantity_ordered) as item_purchasepricetotal,
sum(distinct cart_discounttotal) as total_discount,
sum(customerorderpos.itemtotal - (customerorderpos.purchase_price * customerorderpos.quantity_ordered) - (select distinct cart_discounttotal)) as item_earningstotal,
sum(distinct cart_total_shipping) as total_shipping,
sum(distinct cart_total_tax) as total_tax,
sum(distinct cart_total_complete) as total_complete
from customerorder
inner join customerorderpos on customerorder.customerorderid = customerorderpos.customerorderid
where
customerorder.datetime >= 1351494000 and
customerorder.status_cancelled = "0"
group by day(from_unixtime(customerorder.datetime))
order by customerorder.datetime
```

When I enter the query in PhpMyAdmin in works fine and shows the last 7 days orders. But when we run it in our own software it gives an error.

```
$result = $db->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
```

This shows: "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object"

But.... if I take out "where customerorder.datetime >= 1351494000" from the query it works fine.
In other words the query works perfectly until I want to limit it to a specific time. Customerorder.datetime is an int(11) column with a timestamp.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What error do you get from MySQL?

Comment: `var_dump($result);` - **ALWAYS** use `var_dump` to check that the data in the variable is not the data you think there is

Comment: Hi Mike, var_dump shows bool(false). If I take the 'customerorder.datetime >= 1351494000 and ' out so it just says 'where customerorder.status_cancelled = "0"' it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I found the problem though, it was (of course) my own mistake!
The actual SQL syntax was fine, I just had an error in our own software (the $query was running though a clean-up function that replaced the ">=" characters, making the query invalid).

Sorry for wasting your time :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is on this part

```
      customerorder.datetime >= 1351494000
```

Make it like this:

```
      customerorder.datetime >= '1351494000'
```

You have to enclose it to make it work. Hope this help.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your quick reply! But no, I tried that, it still gives the same error whether it's enclosed or not...

Comment: What exactly the error that you are getting? Remember to either use single quote or double quote. It depends on how you declare your sql query.

Comment: Isn't suppose to be mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ?

Comment: @user1149244: quotes for numbers? Please never advice that anymore